# Pass Response Value in Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, axios

i already call the axios and show using console log if it is successful or not already, However i wanted to pass the axios post response value to my vue component and display the response in my vue component in order for me to make a condition. Is there any way to do it? I try some other part but no luck. Kindly guide me.

main.vue

```js
  methods: {
    onClicked() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('Clickme', this.data)
        .then(() => {
          alert("Success");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          alert("Error");
        })
    }
  }
```

clicked.js

```js
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            clicked(username, password)
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log("---->>>> : ");
                    const data = resp.data.data
                    console.log(username, password);
                    console.log(resp);
                    console.log("statresponse.status : " + resp.data.status);
                    console.log("statresponse.message : " + resp.data.message);

                    console.log("statresponse.inside message : " + resp.data.data.message);
                    // console.log("USER.JS RESPONSE: " + resp.data.status);
                    // console.log("USER.JS RESPONSE: " + resp.data.message);

                    setToken(data.token)
                    commit('SET_TOKEN', data.token)

                    resolve()
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing main.vue to:

```js
 onClicked() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('Clickme', this.data)
        .then((response) => {
          //Do whatever you want with your response
          alert("Success");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          alert("Error");
        })
    }
```

and change clicked.js to:

```js
 resolve(resp.data.data)
```

This will make so the promise resolves the response data.

However if you make the http request in your store/using vuex, what you probably want to do is commit a mutation to put the response into your state - and then map the state from your component.

Comment: Thank youuuuu!! i try that its working. Thank you very muchhhh